# When using tmux how can I see the total output of one pane?

Tags: tmux

I am using an application that uses tmux with multiple panes
I know the basics of how to travel between panes.

So I move to one pane with Ctrl+B and arrows.
Then when I am in one pane that I found interesting I do Ctrl+B Z and I could see the pane as an entire terminal. (Zoom)

The problem is when I am there I can see the latest output of that pane but I cannot go up to see what happened before that. I would like to do that.

How can I scroll the other outputs in a pane in tmux?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can scroll outputs in tmux by running the following key combinations:

`CTRL-B` and then the `[` key.   (Enters "Scroll mode")

You can now use the up and down arrow keys on your keyboard to scroll through the output. To exit, just press `ESC` or `q`

Comment: I am sorry, what is the "[" for?. Is it for something similar to Pg ups and downs?

Comment: @KansaiRobot That’s the key your supposed to press

Comment: no, I meant what was that combination for?

Comment: I don’t think you’ve read the answer in full

Comment: I was just asking, no prob. I am going to run the program now, and try the combination. Then I ll report

Comment: @KansaiRobot awesome. Let me know if you have any other troubles, I’m happy to help

Comment: Awesome. I m still in the midde of that but it seems it works. To quit I ll try esc later

Comment: mmm Esc did not seem to work but "q" did work to quit scroll mode

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225609/discussion-between-lemon-and-kansairobot).